# Can't access node-taxonomy.tpl.php through page-taxonomy-term.tpl in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

I've been trying to customize taxonomy page template in my Drupal 6 site.

What I did was

- created `page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php`
- created `node-taxonomy.tpl.php`
- Entered following code in template.php:

  ```
   function templateNAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy') {
      $suggestions = array(
        'node-taxonomy'
      );
      $vars['template_files'] = array_merge($vars['template_files'], $suggestions);
    }
  ```

My Taxonomy page is picking up `page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php` correctly but it just doesn't pick up `node-taxonomy.tpl.php` and I tried just almost everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below few tips and attempts to do:

- if you are working on subtheme, copy node.tpl.php from parent theme to the folder under subtheme (mandatory in drupal 6 themes).
- try to check if the node-taxonomy suggestions is correctly added in
  object $node. var_dump($node) inside the main node.tpl.php and check
  if is present.
- last tips: check the permission of the file tpl, maybe is not readable from the web server.